# How to get current URL of webview in windows 8 Apps | C#, XMAL

Tags: c#, windows, webview, windows-store-apps

How can I get the URL of currently opened page in webview?

Actually I want to create a login scenario. so that I can integrate my university site for real-time notifications of assignments and quiz's.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be noted that the WebView_LoadCompleted event has been deprecated & is/will be obsolete.  It may not be available after Windows 8.1 so you should use the NavigationCompleted event instead.

```
private void myWebView_NavigationCompleted(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationCompletedEventArgs args)
    {    
        string myUrl = sender.Source.ToString();    
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

Another idea would be to use InvokeScript and get the info from the document using javascript. Something like:

```
var url = await myWebView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new String[] { "document.location.href;" });
```

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you!  I was searching for a way to grab the URL from a WebView, and came across your solution.  I tested it in my app and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

There's no direct property. You have to use `LoadCompleted` event.

```
private void WebView_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Uri.ToString());
}
```